# best way for deployment of django-channels in real server

Tags: django, apache, nginx, deployment, django-channels

I have a website written with django and use django-channels. I can test this with "manage.py runserver" and it's work fine.

But in real world you can't use this method to run your website. Apache and Nginx are not serving django-channels (Websocket) and you should use alongside server s.a. Daphne but it's very complicated to config this approach. and i can do this for one time and forget that :(

I'm locking for the best approach to deployment django-channels app in real world.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use Apache for HTTP requests and Daphne for websockets.

please have a look at my answer in this other post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54844887/10767822

Answer (score 0):

For production, we should use webservers like Nginx or Apache to server. Since these servers doesn't have ASGI support, we have to use [ASGI servers](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asgi.html) like daphne or uvicorn.

Install daphne or uvicorn and start a process with

```
uvicorn avilpage.asgi --log-level critical --workers 4
```

or

```
daphne avilpage.asgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0 --port 9000 --verbosity 1
```

This will start a separate process to serve ASGI requests ie WebSockets. From here we can follow the same process as deploying a normal HTTP web application.

I have written a blog post on [deploying channels to production](https://avilpage.com/2018/05/deploying-scaling-django-channels.html).